# JpaSpecificationExecutor JOIN + ORDER BY in Specification

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a query using a JOIN and ORDER BY and want to use it within my repository using the Criteria Api.

Here I found, how to wrap such a query into a CriteriaQuery ([Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html)).

```
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
Join<Pet, Owner> owner = cq.join(Pet_.owners);
cq.select(pet);
cq.orderBy(cb.asc(owner.get(Owner_.lastName),owner.get(Owner_.firstName)));
```

On the other side, I found some examples to use the Criteria Api in Combination with a JpaRepository ([example](http://www.cubrid.org/wiki_ngrinder/entry/how-to-create-dynamic-queries-in-springdata)).

The Problem is that all methods in the repository expect a Specification:

```
T findOne(Specification<T> spec);
```

which is always build like this:

```
public static Specification<PerfTest> statusSetEqual(final Status... statuses) {
    return new Specification<PerfTest>() {
        @Override

        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<PerfTest> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.not(root.get("status").in((Object[]) statuses));
        }
    };

}
```

So at one side I know how to create a CriteriaQuery, and on the other side I need a Specification which is build from a Predicate, and I can not figure out how to parse the CriteriaQuery into a Specification/Predicate.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try something like this (I assumed pet has many owners):

```
public static Specification<Pet> ownerNameEqual(String ownerName) {
        return new Specification<Pet>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Pet> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                Join<Pet, Owner> owners = root.join("owners");
                criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get("id")));
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(owners.get("name"), ownerName);
            }
        };
    }
```

This is just an example to search all pets whose at least one owner has name equal to *ownerName*

But you could add a method `List<Pet> findByOwnersNameOrderByIdDesc(String ownerName);` in your repository instead (as an equivalent to Specification).

Comment: wow, I did not expected this to work, because i did not expect that criteriaQuery is used later, but it works

Comment: Thanks, still I don't get results. I have one-to-many with FetchType.LAZY could it be the issue, how to handle it

Comment: Hi I am commenting here for the different approach is there any way in JPA spefication to maintain the order of elements in IN query as a result of outcome after the query fired?

Comment: @jacub-bibro: But what if after chaining multiple Specifications, I'd just like to order by an attribute in the end? If I keep `criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get("id")));` only, should I return null from `toPredicate` method?