# Spring JPA Specification with Sort

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I am using Spring JPA.

To be more precise I am using a Repository which extends `JpaRepository` and `JpaSpecificationExecutor` because I require pagination, filtering and sorting.

Now I have the pagination and filtering all working just fine, but I cannot get sorting to work as well.

I notice with some disappointment that `JpaSpecificationExecutor` has `findAll()` methods:

```
findAll(Specification, Pageable);
findAll(Specification, Sort);
```

But the one I need:

```
findAll(Specification, Pageable, Sort); //or something like this
```

does not exist!

So, Plan B, include Sorting in the Specification.

With the help of the Accepted Answer to this question: [JpaSpecificationExecutor JOIN + ORDER BY in Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203878/jpaspecificationexecutor-join-order-by-in-specification) I put together the following:

```
private Specification<MainEntity> matches() {
    return new Specification<MainEntity>() {

        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MainEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            //Attempt to sort by Surname, has no effect
            query.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("surname")));

            //add string filters
            for (String field : stringFilterMap.keySet()) {
                String valuePattern = stringFilterMap.get(field);
                predicates.add(cb.like(root.get(field), "%"+valuePattern+"%"));
            }

            //...snip...

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }
    };      
}
```

Where `springFilterMap` is an instance field, `Map<String,String>` whose keys are field names and values are filters values.

Above you will see my attempt to order by Surname, but this seems to have no effect.

What am I doing wrong; & how can I achieve Sorting along with Pagination and Filtering?

Comment: do you mind using spring query dsl . you dont need to write any code for sorting. follow spring doc or i can give some direction. i have used it and it avoids extra coding explicitly. you just pass in your parameters and asc/desc , it gives you appropriate result

Comment: I encountered your question when looking for a similar problem. I'm using the repository in my Controller, and when using a Controller you can use `@PageableDefault(size = 10, sort = "sortColumn", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable` in your method signature to get an automatically filled Pageable object (just like a @PathVariable for instance).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [PageRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html), which is an implementation of [Pageable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html), and implements paging and sorting at once, like you want it. For example through [this constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#PageRequest-int-int-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort-):

```
public PageRequest(int page, int size, Sort sort)
```

UPDATE: 
Since Spring Data JPA 2.0 the above constructor is deprecated and you should use the static factory method [of](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#of-int-int-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort-):

```
public static PageRequest of(int page, int size, Sort sort)
```

Comment: Does this sort inside of the page, or sort data from repository and then paginate it?

Comment: Sorting  by column of inner child entity like Entity1.Entity2.Entity3 doe not work.