# How can I order a list using the CriteriaQuery in my Specifications?

Tags: java, spring-boot, criteria-api

I'm trying to order the lists returned by my JpaRepository. I'm using `Specification` classes rather than the `@Query` annotation, and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203878/jpaspecificationexecutor-join-order-by-in-specification/37241807), I'm supposed to use a `CriteriaQuery` object.

My specification is currently as follow :

```
public class MessageSpecification {

    public static Specification<MessageEntity> hasDemandeId(Long demandeId) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            // TODO : order the list
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join(MessageEntity_.demande).get(DemandeEntity_.idTechnique), demandeId);
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have here two entity classes `MessageEntity` and `DemandeEntity` where `MessageEntity` has a property referencing a `DemandeEntity`. So in this specification, I'm getting a list of `MessageEntity` that have the specified `DemandeEntity`'s ID.

Now I would like to do the equivalent of an `ORDER BY Message.ID`. To do so, I tried using the `CriteriaQuery` object in my predicate (variable `query`) :

```
return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(MessageEntity_.idTechnique)));
    return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join(MessageEntity_.demande).get(DemandeEntity_.idTechnique), demandeId);
};
```

But it does not work, it's still returning the list in the same order whether I use `criteriaBuilder.desc()` or `criteriaBuilder.asc()`.

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong, how am I supposed to use that `CriteriaQuery` object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no solution with the Specification class so I decided to use the Sort class to order my list :

```java
public Sort sortByIdTechnique(){
    return new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "idTechnique");
}
```

JpaRepository's `findAll` accept a Sort object as a parameter as well as a Specification:

```java
List<MessageEntity> messages = repository.findAll(MessageSpecification.hasDemandeId(idDemande), sortByIdTechnique());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join(MessageEntity_.demande).get(DemandeEntity_.idTechnique), demandeId))
            .orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(MessageEntity_.idTechnique)))
            .distinct(true)
            .getRestriction();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work :( I've tried using `asc()` and `desc()` once again and I have the same result @Artiow