# Apply Order By in JPA Specifications

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I'm writing code with the JPA Specifications:

Snippet1:

```
Specification.where(withTopics())
        .and(withCar())
        .and(withInsurance())
        // how to add order by
```

Where each condition method has structure like:

```
public static Specification<Page> withCar(String type) {
    return new Specification<Page>() {
      @Override
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Page> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return // logic return cb
      }
    };
}
```

I want to add the the order by conditions.

I've written the order by expressions:

```
public static Specification<Page> orderByConditions(String input1, String input2) {
    return new Specification<Page>() {
      @Override
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Page> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        Expression<Object> cases = cb.selectCase()
                .when(cb.equal(cb.lower(root.get("carn_ame")), inputTopic.toLowerCase()), 1)
                .when(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("insurance_name")), "%" + inputTitle.toLowerCase() + "%"), 2)
                .otherwise(3);
        Order order = cb.desc(cases);
        cb.createQuery().orderBy(order);
        // what to return
      }
    }
}
```

What should I return from my `orderByConditions()`, so I can apply it to my specifications in **Snippet1**?

But how should I add it to my specifications?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JpaSpecificationExecutor JOIN + ORDER BY in Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203878/jpaspecificationexecutor-join-order-by-in-specification)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I looked into it, but not able to figure out what `criteriaBuilder.equal`should I apply with `criteriaQuery.orderBy`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a condition/predicate you can return a "no condition" 1 = 1

```
return cb.equal(cb.literal(1), 1);
```

Comment: Seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Usually the Specification is used to create the Predicate and not only the order by clause. But this no condition is very common. So the database will remove this anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using named query, but this insight will really help me in future.